# Cryptsetup hanging after passphrase entered

Tags: encryption, cryptsetup, disk-encryption

I am currently looking to recover some data for a friend from an internal HDD removed from a laptop that they had encrypted using LUKS. They can't really tell me much more else as somebody else encrypted it for them but they do know the passcode and it was running a flavour of Linux as the OS. I am looking to decrypt the data to then recover it onto a second USB device.

I have used the following commands to decrypt it:-

```
losetup /dev/loop1 /mnt/hdd #hdd being the encrypted disk
mmls /mnt/hdd #just to check it has mounted
```

Returns:-

```
DOS Partition table
Offset Sector: 0
000 .... Primary Table
001 .... Unallocated
002 .... Linux
003 .... Linux
004 .... Unallocated

kpartx -a /dev/loop1
kpartx -l /dev/loop1
```

Returns:

```
loop1p1: 0 1024000 /dev/loop1 2048
loop1p2: 0 624115712 /dev/loop1 1026048
```

I then enter the command:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/loop1ps decrypted-directory --verbose
```

*I enter the passphrase*

```
Key slot 1 unlocked
```

It then hangs with no further output.
From what I've read, it should print "command successful" to console but this doesn't seem to happen. I've left this for 12+ hours too just in case this is the decryption process.

I assume this isn't the decryption process as I would assume there would be some verbose logging to terminal?

Comment: `cryptsetup` is often used to encrypt the whole disk, i.e. the LUKS header appears before the partition table.  From your question it appears that you can see a partition table (which means only certain partitions are encrypted).  What does `file -s` give on each of the devices (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2`)?  `file` understands LUKS headers.